# Syntax to Define an Entire Row as Range

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, I can define an **entire column** as a range and address individual cells in that range like:

```
Sub headache()
   Dim r As Range
   Set r = Range("A:A")
   MsgBox r(1).Address & vbCrLf & r(2).Address
End Sub
```

If I try to do the same thing with an **entire row**:

```
Sub headache2()
   Dim r As Range
   Set r = Rows(1)
   MsgBox r(1).Address & vbCrLf & r(2).Address
End Sub
```

I do not get the individual cells in the range.  My workaround is:

```
Set r = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Columns.Count))
```

I can't believe this is the simplest way to make the range...........any suggestions??

Comment: The same thing would be using Set r = Range("1:1") which works by the way...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
   Set r = Rows(1).Cells
```

or just use:

```
   MsgBox r.Cells(1).Address & vbCrLf & r.Cells(2).Address
```

but note that accessing the Range (or Cells) property of a range using an index will never be restricted to that range alone.

Answer (score 7):

The row equivalent to

```
Set r = Range("A:A")
```

would be

```
Set r = Range("1:1")
```

I was curious and ran these tests building on Rory's answer.  Maybe someone else can explain the addresses being the same and the counts being different.

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print Me.Range("A:A").Count '1048576
    Debug.Print Me.Columns(1).Count '1
    Debug.Print Me.Columns(1).Cells.Count '1048576

    Debug.Print Me.Range("1:1").Count '16384
    Debug.Print Me.Rows(1).Count '1
    Debug.Print Me.Rows(1).Cells.Count '16384

    'interseting to me since the counts are different but the addresses are the same
    Debug.Print Me.Range("1:1").Address '$1:$1
    Debug.Print Me.Rows(1).Address '$1:$1
    Debug.Print Me.Rows(1).Cells.Address '$1:$1
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would the addresses be different? The count is counting either rows or cells, but the address always refers to the same range.

Comment: First, thank you for responding......I now understand that a single column can be either a **Column** Object or a **Range** Object......the addresses are the same, but the counts are different because there is only one Column, but many Cells.